# Getting into the Sound Design Department of Disney Imagineering...?

Tags: design

I've been working professionally as a sound editor/designer for various TV shows and movies for the past couple of years.  My absolute dream however, is to design the sound for disney theme parks and Disney movies. I've always been taken aback by the detail in the sound and the creation in general of Disney theme parks and their entertainment.  Even to this day, I get chills just being in the company of products of that creativity.

I'd love to pick someone's brain, hear their stories and take any advice you are willing to give, to ultimately become a Disney Imagineer. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Get to personally know people who work there. And ask them these questions.